# Trying to add a key into a table

Tags: php, pdo, insert

i'm trying to add a key into a table i don't know why it isn't working, i've echo'd all the stuff that i'm inputting and they seem to echo, so the issue isn't with my variables maybe with my syntax? looked over it 3 times and i couldn't spot the problem. Maybe my structure aswell?

Code:

```
                    $SQLInsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `Keys` VALUES(NULL, :Key, :Activated, :Blacklisted, :Timestamp, :DATE, NULL)");
        $zeroString = '0';
        $oneString = '1';
        $emptyString = '';
        $SQLInsert -> execute(array(':Key' => $rank['key'], ':Activated' => $oneString, ':Blacklisted' => $zeroString, ':Timestamp' => $emptyString, ':DATE' => $emptyString));
```

As for the table:
[image: img]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: remove first NULL, you DB field for ID is NOT NULL, add '' instead, or specify fields while inserting

Comment: if Activated/Blacklisted are `int`, why are you inserting a **STRING**? mysql and php won't care, but seems kinda pointless to go out of your way to name a variable as "string", then use it on an int field. and if this insert is not executing, then you should check the return value from the execute call, or at least enable exceptions and error_reporting.

Comment: @MuhammedM.: inserting null into an auto_increment field is explicitly supported to tell the DB to generate a new ID value, even if the field has been defined as notnull

Comment: @Mureinik I don't get any errors, that's the issue i have error loggin on and it just won't give me any errors, it won't go in the table though.

Comment: @MarcB I have them enabled, i don't see any errors. :/

Comment: then check return values. pdo returns boolean false on failure by default. `$res = $sql->execute(...);  if ($res === false) { die($sql->error()); }` or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB Still doesn't tell me the error, really odd

Comment: By default, PDO errors silently. Make it throw an exception, and ensure you have `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (always when developing code) and configure PDO with `$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` before calling the code you have posted. If there's an error, it will be printed to the screen.

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelBerkowski